# Error when start of the apache2 service: version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssl, openssl

I'm using a Debian Wheezy server where I have installed apache2, php5 and libapache2-mod-php5 packages via apt-get. But when I'm trying to start the apache2 the follow error occurs:

```
service apache2 start

[....] Starting web server: apache2apache2: Syntax error on line 244 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: symbol TLSv1_1_server_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

The apache2 service starts successfuly when I disable the php5 service.

I have just reinstall the libssl1.0.0 and openssl apt-get packages, but that problem still persists.

Comment: I don't know much about apache but it may be useful to supply line 244 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, since it seems to originate there. You can get it easily using this command: `sed -n '244p' etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: It is not generally considered a good behaviour to cross-post the same question to several SE sites. On top of that this question seems to have very little to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Please, if you have time, consider revisiting [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). All questions are worth of asking but not all questions are worth asking in Stack Overflow.